# how can I get a url segment?

Tags: php, mysql, html

I have the last url segment of the following url

http://something.com/somefunc/10

that is the number 10;

My real problem is that I have a form that I need to post an action of the url

```
<form action="../something/somefunc/<?php echo $id>">
   //some code
</form>
```

after receiving the posted stuff, I would like to still be able to get the id of the product under consideration. I think now that form's action url is the only way I know that can help retain such an id. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

[**UPDATE**]

Uhmmm, all the answers below are correct, don't know which one to choose as the best reply.

Comment: First one would be fair.

Comment: Placing the id in a hidden input field would seem to be the simplest and require least amount of additional code on the backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.You could pass the product id using POST as a hidden input in your form:

```
<input name="productid" id="productid" type="hidden" value="<?=$id ?>">
```

and in the page you post to:

```
<? if (isset($_POST['productid'])) $id = $_POST['productid'] ?>
```

2.Alternatively use GET & pass it on the querystring

```
action="../something/somefunc/[processingpage]?productid=<?=$id ?>"
```

and in [processingpage]:

```
<? if (isset($_GET['productid'])) $id = $_GET['productid'] ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Something along these lines may work...

```
$url = 'http://'. $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$parts = parse_url($url);
$path = $parts['path'];
$keys = explode('/', $path);
echo $keys[4]; // `corresponding to the 4th url word`
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: You might use `$id = array_pop($keys);` to get the last url segment if the number of segments varies.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if I'm misunderstanding, but can't you get the ID of your posted form via the $_POST array?
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_post.asp

Alternately, if the ID is in a URL parameter, you can access it via the $_GET variable:
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_get.asp

Answer (score 1):

You can put a hidden input with the id

`<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">`